# Taking centrifugal insted of centripetal changes friction direction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Let's say a car is moving in circular motion then what will be the direction of friction on tyre of car ?

And if we take centrifugal instead of centripetal force then will the direction of friction change or not ?

Comment: Rule of thumb: If a coordinate change, which you can make entirely in your head, changes a physical observable, then you have probably made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an inertial frame of reference we need a centripetal force to make the car go in a circle instead of in a straight line. Friction provides this centripetal force so it is directed towards the centre of the circle.

In the car's frame of reference, the car experience centrifugal force. In its own frame of reference the car appears to be in equilibrium so this centrifugal force must be balanced by an equal and opposite force. Friction provides the force that balances the centrifugal force. So once again friction is directed towards the centre of the circle.

So these two different approaches give the same direction and magnitude for friction.

Comment: I have this confusion because of a question which was like          in a truck block is lying at rest when truck starts moving with acceleration a then block will fall down in t time (distance from the end point was given) also there was friction..... when I solve this taking non inertial frame or inside the truck answer came but when I solved this with taking inertial frame of reference when observer will be at ground then answer came but the block is not falling it was going for inside truck... If you are able to get it so please if not then it is my English fault.

Answer (score 0):

When you jump from an inertia frame into a non-inertial frame or the other way round all the real forces do not change in either magnitude or direction.
All that happens is that to make Newton's second law work in the non-inertial frame a force is added which in this case is a centrifugal force.

So in this example the friction force stays the same and in the inertial frame of the ground the frictional force produces the centripetal acceleration whereas in the non-inertial frame of the car the addition of a centrifugal force equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the frictional force means that the net force on the car is zero and the car's acceleration is zero.